# Intellij Python Selenium Driver Function is not getting called from another function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Driver function is not getting called in another function - website does not open

Website is opened (twice for some reason - better than nothing) when not using driver function in another function

Why the following code does not open the website?

```
   from selenium import webdriver

   def mybrowserdriver():
    chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/browserdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
    return chromedriver

  def opensite():
    mybrowserdriver().get('https://www.bing.com')
    mybrowserdriver().maximize_window()
```

Why does the following code opens the website?

```
   from selenium import webdriver

   def mybrowserdriver():
    chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/browserdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
    return chromedriver

   mybrowserdriver().get('https://www.bing.com')
   mybrowserdriver().maximize_window()
```

What could be the explanation that code works outside function but it does not inside another function?

Comment: "Why the following code does not open the website? " Because you never call `opensite()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first lines of codes essentially do nothing, the second lines execute the two lines in the end.

For the first you just define two functions: `mybrowserdriver()` and `opensite()` and never call them.

In the second one, the last two lines are the ones that are actually executed, thus the function `mybrowserdriver()` is called twice. This also means that the constructor for the `webdriver.Chrome()` inside the `mybrowserdriver()` function is called twice - resulting in the two browser windows, that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the first block is right here:

```
  def opensite():
```

You define a function `opensite()` which calls `myseleniumdriver()`, but `opensite()` is never called, so Selenium never launches.

In your second code block, you call `myseleniumdriver()` directly from the python script, which executes regardless.

If you want your first script to work, try this:

```
   from selenium import webdriver

   def mybrowserdriver():
    chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/browserdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
    return chromedriver

  def opensite():
    mybrowserdriver().get('https://www.bing.com')
    mybrowserdriver().maximize_window()

  opensite()
```